# onKeyDown event not called the first time?

Tags: android, keypress, onkeydown

I have an onKeyDown event which wont recognise the first key press (wont even enter the event, i have tested by producing a 'toast' output). On the second key press and after, it works perfectly. If I click on another element on the screen and try the key press again, it yet again needs another key press to get it going. Here is the code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        scorered.performClick();
        return true;


    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
        red_m1.performClick();
        return true;


        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT: 
        scoreblue.performClick();
        return true;


        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2: 
        blue_m1.performClick();
        return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            finish();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

I have been stumped for hours so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you enable setFocusableInTouchMode? and don't you need to call super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); inside keyDown()?

Comment: unfortunately both those didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure, there are good reasons for such behaviour, but do not think, that removing focus is a good solution. My workaround is to fire a keydown event, that "activate" regular onKeyDown functionality. Here is snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP);
    }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, a work-around is to remove the view focus before pressing any DPAD key. It works in my case. I am having exactly the same issue: When a view of Android Activity is on focus, the very first DPAD key event, that is, the `KeyDown` event, is ignored: None of these methods are called: `onUserInteraction()`, `dispatchKeyEvent()`, `onKeyDown()`. However, subsequent DPAD key events - `KeyUp`, `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, ..., can be captured.

Note that this issue does not occur with soft keys (Home, Previous, Recents) nor with hard button keys (BUTTON_A, BUTTON_B, BUTTON_X, BUTTON_Y).

Comment: In the constructor of your derived class of SurfaceView, add setFocusableInTouchMode(true) just after calling setFocusable(true).